# how to compile Nginx when it will be used with Tornado

Tags: python, nginx, tornado

first there is this jewel: [the best explication for nginx configuration](https://calomel.org/nginx.html) and i've found that it will be better to compile the source only with what we'll need! so my questions are simple:

Which are modules that will only need when compiling Nginx when it will used only to serve static file.

Is it useful to make compile with the SSL support? or let only Tornado handle the SSL?

How about using Tornado to handle open connection and Nginx Timeout configurations values ( **client_body_timeout**, **client_header_timeout**, **keepalive_timeout** ) will they be bigger or smaller values ???

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and most reliable method will be to use nginx as a reverse proxy for tornado. Have nginx handle all the frontend connections, as well as SSL. This will also allow you to run multiple tornado processes (up to # of CPU cores) if you need more processing power.

Any other configuration will depend on your specific application.

So I would just start by adding `--with-http_ssl_module`.

You can see all the configure options with `./configure --help`. If you want to remove more of the standard modules, you can figure out what you need by process of elimination - most of the `--without-*` options (other than proxy) could probably be used in your case. It's really up to you, and what you want to use.

Comment: so what about compiling? which module do i make --without if i only use Nginx to serve static files?

Comment: The default config is pretty bare. Worrying about the `--without-*` options right now is somewhat premature.

Comment: but the problem, for example in Apache, i've only to "comment" the line where i want to exclude a module, but in ngnix everything is embedded, so it will use memory?

Comment: No, if you don't use the module, it wont use any memory. The executable size is so small, you're talking about saving a few Kilobytes. The default nginx executable is 768K on ubuntu. I just compiled a 64bit nginx, excluding most everything, and it rolls in at 421K stripped.

Comment: and last question, the ssl module, does this make sense to use it since tornado has the ssl support?

Comment: Yes, use nginx for SSL. It wil be better performing, and easier to manage.

Comment: thank you for the answer, now it's time for me to start "ngininig" and "tornadoing" ^_^

Comment: > so it will use memory?

Yes, but very little. Nginx is very lightweight. Worry about optimizing the data layer, the HTTP stuff (headers, mimification, gzip, the obvious stuf - this is often nginx configuration), the python code, then maybe nginx. The performance impact of nginx will usually be minimal. I'm not an expert, but only issue I've ever head of with nginx is chosing the right SSL protocol - sometimes it's configured to prefer a slower encryption method, but even then it's not likely to be your biggest problem.